# Значение блока css в php

Tags: php, переменные, css

Здравствуйте, очень нужна помощь свиязи с одной нашумевшей проблемой.
Я имею блок CSS. Он отображает мне цифровое значение то бишь "рекорд".
Я хочу что бы в конце игры этот рекорд попадал в php переменную $score.
Что бы финальный счет был в данной переменной. Дело в том что я пробовал присвоить переменной значение через вот такое действие:

```
$score = '<див class='score'>0<(/)div>';
```

Но безрезультатно, мне лишь выводило блок, значение не воспринимало... 
Стоит вопрос : 'Как присвоить переменной $score значение .score?'
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. Что нужно то? То говоришь о рекорде, то о CSS стиле. Может пример хоть докинь, что бы наглядно понять.

Comment: вы, кажется путаете клиентские и серверные скрипты. Еще раз google://Ajax

Answer (score 3):

PHP - скриптовый язык, и выполняется он, соответсвенно, на сервере.

После того, как PHP-скрипт выполнится на сервере, сервер отдает результат своей работы(в виде html в перемешку с css и javascript), который мы и видим в браузере.

Почитайте теорию. Например, [это](http://www.codeharmony.ru/materials/30). Без основ далеко не уйдете, как видите.

Решение на самом деле - использовать ajax, но для начала настоятельно рекомендую изучить основы. Желаю удачию.